# How to add html tag in text domain wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i add a html tag like span and css clas on "No vendemos en %s" to render

```
<span class="something">No vendemos en</span> %s
```

there is my php code

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'No se han encontrado opciones de envío para %s.' :
            $translated_text = __( 'No vendemos en %s', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: Just put it in there.

Comment: if you want to print then printf(__( '%s Hello %s world', 'textdomain' ), '<span>', '</span>' );

Answer (score 0):

Use php echo the string of the html you want to add, with variables defined in php if needed:

```
<?php
$phpValue = 'something';
?>

<html>
<p>Trying to add php info: <?php echo $phpValue; ?></p>
</html>
```

You can do the same with echoing html tags and content:

```
<?php
 $phpValue = 'something';

echo '<div class="someCSSClass"><p>Trying to add php info:' . $phpValue . '</p></div>';

?>
```

Comment: In your specific example it'd be the full html, with span tag and class, or whatever else you wanted:
<span class="something">'No vendemos en %s'